# Text postioning in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a problem with positioning.
I have this page:
[PAGE1](http://kukubaczek.cf/test/1/)
And I want to add text with text "Merry Christmas" like this:
[PAGE2](http://kukubaczek.cf/test/2/)
But when this text is on page, snows not from the top...
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

PS: Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following canvas rules so it doesn't get pushed down by other elements:

```
#canvas {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Ok, now like this: http://kukubaczek.cf/test/3/ I want to snow is behind the snowman.

Comment: You're welcome! :)  `#scene {z-index: 1;}`